# Mac with 2 monitors, how do i switch virtual desktops on one monitor only?

Tags: macos, display

I have 2 monitors for mac, one extended the other.

How do i switch virtual desktops on one monitor only?

For example, When I do 4 fingers swipe left/right on screen1,  I expect the switching happens on screen1 only.

BUT both monitors will switch virtual desktops at the same time, how do i avoid that?

Comment: What OS X version do You have? If Mavericks or newer go to **Preferences** -> **Mission Control** -> **Displays have separagte Spaces**.

Comment: Although this answer was placed here after I put it as an answer it would be helpful for you to accept it so it is listed as solved.

Answer (score 42):

I am not on a My Mac at the moment, but in the Mission Control Preferences there is a setting to have the spaces work independently. Go to **Preferences** -> **Mission Control** -> **Displays have separate Spaces**.

[image]

In Ventura, "Displays have separate spaces" setting has now moved to Settings > Desktop & Dock.

Answer (score 5):

To add to @markhunte, the switching of desktops seems to depend on where the focus or mouse, is. I have 2 external monitors and 3 spaces on my primary display. When I add a space to an external monitor, the key-combo of <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd><-</kbd> or <kbd>-></kbd> will move the space where the active app or my mouse is located.